# Laravel 8 Helpers vs Controllers Performance

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I wonder if there are any differences between putting a function in helpers or just putting it on controllers?
For example, a function to count how much data in database,
In helpers the code looks like:

```
function countData($status = 'active')
{
    $data = Models::where('status', 'like', $status)->count();
    return $data;
}
```

And in controllers the code looks like:

```
$status = 'active';
$countData = Models::where('status', 'like', $status)->count();
return view('some.view', compact('countData');
```

Which one is the best, using helpers or controllers?
Is there any way to check the performances between those two?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share sample code examples?

Comment: I will update the question and include the code

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Ok, both code don't seem to be the same. One has Pengaduan and another one has Models. Efficacy would be approximately the same for both approaches but you need to design in terms of ease of use and reuse.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change the second code, already updated (again)..

Comment: Forget about performance. In this case, it is about the design. Performance is more or less the same.

Comment: Okay i see.. Thank you for your answer buddy.  @nice_dev

Comment: No problem. Also have a look at what [`traits`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are. You might find it useful.

Comment: Checking it now, thank you buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller method is to be used with an HTTP request. A helper can be used anywhere in the code As the same bootstrap is called if you are responding to an HTTP request.
Both approaches are equally slow since you're querying the database. That adds the most time, therefore fiddling with micro-optimizations won't get you anywhere, it's a waste of effort.

Comment: Ah I see, so helper can be called from anywhere, like from any views for example, correct?

Comment: @VTrace that is correct. but dont fill up your app with helpers to which you use once. also don't spend to much time Over optimising your app. create it in the controller, then later if you need it some where else move it.